# Replace Text with Formatted Text on Linux

Tags: linux, search, replace, awk, sed

I'm looking for a way to replace the text between positions 10 and 17 in a file with a Linux command or script.  For example, I'd like to replace the date text 20140101 with 01/01/2014.

I'm hoping this is something I can in a single command from the command line with maybe sed or awk?

Comment: This question is under-specified. Is the text always in the same position? Is the format always exactly that? Are you only trying to perform that single change?

Comment: Yes it is always in the same location.  Yes the format is always exactly the same (other than the date changes).  Yes I only need to preform this single change to every line in the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `sed`, you can capture the first 9 chars in a capture group that would be placed as is. The remaining would be broken in 3 capture groups and re-arranged as you desire.

Something like:

```
sed -r 's#(.{9})(.{4})(.{2})(.{2})#\1\3/\4/\2#' file
```

If you are on a system that does not have GNU `sed` escape `( ) { }` with `\`.

Answer (score 2):

If all your strings are dates then the best is to use `date` command:

```
$ date -d 20140101 +%m/%d/%Y
01/01/2014
$ date -d 20140923 +"%m-%d-%Y %a %b"
09-23-2014 Tue Sep
```

It is especially great tool to translate number of seconds from 1970 (unix epoch) used in many log files:

```
$ date --date='@1411199063' +"%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S"
09-20-2014 07:44:23
```